# Higher voltage or more amps?

Tags: voltage, current, amperage, brushless-dc-motor, watts

Im planning on building a E-Bike and have made some calculations and only need my 190rpm/V brushless motor to spin around 600 rpm to give me a good speed.

So by this calculation I only need to supply 3.x V.

As I understand it without load the motor will rev up to 600 rpm, but on a bike there will be a pretty big load and high current will be required.

Now because many components doesnt like too much current is it better to have higher voltage so I get more W from V and not as much from A?

Comment: Many components don't like too much voltage.

Comment: What kind of motor are you using, DC? What do you mean by "many components" what other components in the circuit are you worried about.

Comment: @Sada93 Its a brushless DC motor and by many components (its not that many to be honest) Im talking about ESC, battery, BEC and such.

Comment: In my experience a 250 W motor gives good acceleration and about 150 W gives comfortable cruising at about 28 kph. Your battery voltage will have to be high enough to drive the required current through your motor.

Answer (score 4):

First calculate the torque you require - say, to get you, bike and battery up a 10% grade at 20km/h. Then plug in the torque constant for that motor to get the current you need. (If you don't have the torque constant you can calculate it from the speed constant Kv). Then compare that current with the motor's ratings, and your battery system etc. And update the question with your findings.

Then, realise that motor speed doesn't have to be the same as wheel speed, and consider a gearing system such as toothed belt drive... This would allow higher motor speeds and lower torque, for more reasonable voltages and currents.

Comment: Im planning on making a mid drive with small gear on motor and big crank on the bike :)

Comment: What is grade? And how exactly do I calculate the torque?

Comment: @user172650, grade is the incline. So Brian recommended you assume the hill incline is 10% and see what torque you need for that.

Answer (score 2):

Electric motors which need to have good torque from startup (0 RPM) through cruising speed require higher voltages to have high speed.  The electric motorcycle I'm riding has plenty of power in the battery pack, and the hub motor is great at initial acceleration, but it tops out around 55mph due to the 80V pack.  I could have put in twice as many batteries at half current, doubled the voltage, and had a higher top speed, but then I lose a lot of current at the low end and acceleration from 0 is poor.

I'm not terribly interested in adding a transmission, but that's essentially what needs to be done to have the best of both worlds.  Whether electrical (start off with, say, 60V in two series packs, then switch to 120V in a single series pack), or mechanical, a transmission becomes necessary to manage the switchover.

If your bike isn't going to go fast, then put your power in lower voltage, higher current.

If you're going to be cruising at higher speeds regularly, and are willing to sacrifice acceleration, put your power in higher voltage, lower current.

Of course, a lot of this depends on the motor and controller, and given your statement *"...many components [don't] like too much current..."* it sounds like you would be more comfortable with a low current, high voltage setup. There are drawbacks and advantages to both allocations, but if you look around the automotive industry, you'll find that they are focusing more heavily on higher voltages primarily for the reason you state - many active components are priced based on how much current they can handle, and how little they waste.  At lower currents, less is wasted, and components are cheaper. Of course, modern electric cars still handle a huge amount of current even at their 300-400v rating.

Comment: Supposing one wanted the "electrical transmission", would there be a good way of determining when to switch over via the current output of the batteries, or would it need to be done in conjunction with some sort of "current speed" detection?

Comment: I expect it would be different for each motor and controller.  I'd probably set up a test that would provide the torque over speed at the two voltages over various loads, then it should be obvious where the higher voltage provides more torque given a speed and a load.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you still have a lot of research to do in building your e-bike, but you have to start somewhere.

Your question about volts versus amps probably is in reference to the fact that as you transfer the energy from your battery to your e-bike motor, there will be losses of that energy through various factors including losses in the wires that transmit that energy.

As the current through a wire increases, the losses due resistance of the wire resulting in heat, increase at a rate of the square of the current.  In other words if you double the current, you quadruple the losses.  Power loss, \$P=I^2*R\$.

As voltage increases, the losses due to the resistance of the wire could actually drop if power remains the same and current drops relative to voltage increases.  If you take the above equation and substitute for current or I, you get power loss = \$\frac{R}{V^2}\$.  Holding power constant, as voltage increases, losses decrease, and this is likely what you are asking about.

Also, if working at a higher voltage versus a higher current, you can use thinner wires which are easier to work with and much less expensive.

Comment: Yes Im far from making my ebike im just planning everything ahead. So from your answer high voltage and lower amps is better and more efficient than low voltage and more amps?

Comment: @user172650: That's only really true if the only thing you're concerned with is losses in the wiring due to heating. In practice, in a bike, the wires will be relatively short, there will be other considerations (eg high voltage may be a safety risk), and the voltage/current you need to supply will be determined to a great extent by the characteristics of the motor.

Comment: But in the end its the Watts that matter?

Comment: Yes, watts matter the most, but the specs of your motor will matter as well, and torque and top speed will be affected by current and voltage respectively.

Comment: BTW, thank you to whoever edited my equations to make them look cleaner, but you incorrectly edited the second equation and as it stands it is incorrect, but he gist of it is explained in the body of the answer.  I can't figure out how to do the superscript for equations on my tablet!

Answer (score 1):

> many components doesnt like too much current is it better to have higher voltage

ALL electrical components WITHOUT EXCEPTION have maximum currents and voltages they can handle.  Sometimes you can trade off one against the other, but not always.

You should be able to find existing well-matched sets of motors, batteries, control electronics and cables.  (For example, dismantling a mobility scooter.)  If you use this all as-is, then you should be safe.

With respect though, I think your experience with electrics is low enough that experimenting with this would be a spectacularly bad idea.  As in significant risk of death to you and those around you.  The biggest problem isn't electrocution (although that's a real danger); most deaths from electrical problems come from fires, and not having sufficient clue on voltage/current ratings is virtually guaranteed to cause you problems.

I think your minimum entry requirement is a school-leaver-equivalent pass in physics.  If you don't have that (or this was long enough ago that you don't have the information at your fingertips), then I STRONGLY suggest that as a prerequisite to your project.  Physics will also cover the theory behind forces which is highly relevant to your project as well.

With this theory, you can solve this yourself.  Without this theory, I suggest that any well-meaning people giving you advice are actually putting your life in danger by helping you go forward into situations where you can't tell how much danger you are in.

(My own experience: 20 years an engineer, 2 years on national grid stuff, 10+ years on automotive stuff)